# Is there a way to implement unsubscribe for emails send using aws ses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using gcp cloud function to send emails to users using aws ses. I want to include the functionality for users to unsubscribe from emails. Is there any functionality for this in aws ses. I can't find any in the aws documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Belwo snipper is from the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html). So, AWS SES doesn't have this feature out of the box and has to implemented. Also, try to use the "List Unsubscribe Header" as easy option for unsubscribing, more about it [here](https://blog.mailtrap.io/list-unsubscribe-header/).

> When you use Amazon SES to receive mail, you can develop software solutions such as email auto responders, email unsubscribe systems, and applications that generate customer support tickets from incoming emails.